# Icons not extracted for Desktop App Converter app

Tags: windows, desktop-app-converter

Converting my app (an msi installer) with the Desktop App Converter to be published on the winstore. It converts fine except none of the icons are extracted. I get this error:

W_NO_ICONS_EXTRACTED
Icon extraction failed. Using placeholder assets instead. Please check more details: 'Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\icon_extract\Square310x310Logo.scale-400.png' because it does not exist.'

No other warnings or errors. I am using the -AppInstallPath and -AppExecutable params and the verbose logs show that these params are accepted. I also copied the msi installer to a different machine and ran the converter. The icons were extracted without issue on this other machine.

I would ideally like to run the converter on my original build machine. Not sure how to fix this issue, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Make sure Containers is enabled from Programs and Feature.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been addressed in the latest update of the DAC - version 2.1.1.0